# Trying to take a screen capture of a game running in BlueStacks using C#

Tags: c#, android, bluestacks

The code works fine when the target game is running on the version installed from the Windows App Store. The game is a port from an Android game and the Windows version is not receiving updates anymore so I want to run the Android version which is newer using BlueStacks on my PC.

This is the code that works with native Windows version of the game.

```
public GameWindow(int titleHeight)
        {
            GetGameWindow();
            TitleHeight = titleHeight;
        }

        private void GetGameWindow()
        {
            Form1.Rect rectangle = default(Form1.Rect);
            IntPtr intPtr = FindWindow("ApplicationFrameWindow", "Game Window");
            SetForegroundWindow(intPtr);
            GetWindowRect(intPtr, ref rectangle);
            top = rectangle.Top;
            left = rectangle.Left;
            width = rectangle.Right - rectangle.Left;
            height = rectangle.Bottom - rectangle.Top;
            UIClass.ClickBar(this);
        }

        public void BringToFront()
        {
            IntPtr foregroundWindow = FindWindow("ApplicationFrameWindow", "Game Window");
            SetForegroundWindow(foregroundWindow);
        }

        public Bitmap Capture()
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(Width, Height);
            Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(Left, Top, width, height);
            using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
                graphics.CopyFromScreen(new Point(rectangle.Left, rectangle.Top), Point.Empty, rectangle.Size);
            }
            return bitmap;
        }

        public void Capture(string path)
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(Width, Height);
            Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(Left, Top, width, height);
            using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
                graphics.CopyFromScreen(new Point(rectangle.Left, rectangle.Top), Point.Empty, rectangle.Size);
            }
            bitmap.Save(Path.Combine(path, "UT" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + ".jpg"));
            bitmap.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I tried to drill down to the child window"

```
public GameWindow(int titleHeight)
        {
            GetGameWindow();
            TitleHeight = titleHeight;
        }

        private void GetGameWindow()
        {
            Form1.Rect rectangle = default(Form1.Rect);
            IntPtr intPtr = FindWindow("HwndWrapper[Bluestacks.exe;;310d8add-fc43-4c3e-a64b-2cd5f6d0618c]", "BlueStacks");
            SecondBSWin = FindWindowEx(intPtr, IntPtr.Zero, "WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.34f5582_r6_ad1", "BlueStacks Android PluginAndroid");
            ThirdBSWin = FindWindowEx(SecondBSWin, IntPtr.Zero, "WindowsForms10.EDIT.app.0.34f5582_r6_ad1", null);
            ForthBSWin = FindWindowEx(ThirdBSWin, IntPtr.Zero, "BlueStacksApp", "_ctl.Window");
            SetForegroundWindow(ForthBSWin);
            GetWindowRect(ForthBSWin, ref rectangle);
            top = rectangle.Top;
            left = rectangle.Left;
            width = rectangle.Right - rectangle.Left;
            height = rectangle.Bottom - rectangle.Top;
            UIClass.ClickBar(this);
        }

        public void BringToFront()
        {
            IntPtr foregroundWindow = FindWindow("HwndWrapper[Bluestacks.exe;;edc30241-e5fe-4f1b-a9ae-8fcca64ba7b9]", "BlueStacks");
            SetForegroundWindow(foregroundWindow);
            SecondBSWin = FindWindowEx(foregroundWindow, IntPtr.Zero, "WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.34f5582_r6_ad1", "BlueStacks Android PluginAndroid");
            ThirdBSWin = FindWindowEx(SecondBSWin, IntPtr.Zero, "WindowsForms10.EDIT.app.0.34f5582_r6_ad1", null);
            ForthBSWin = FindWindowEx(ThirdBSWin, IntPtr.Zero, "BlueStacksApp", "_ctl.Window");

        }

        public Bitmap Capture()
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(Width, Height);
            Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(Left, Top, width, height);
            using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
                graphics.CopyFromScreen(new Point(rectangle.Left, rectangle.Top), Point.Empty, rectangle.Size);
            }
            return bitmap;
        }

        public void Capture(string path)
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(Width, Height);
            Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(Left, Top, width, height);
            using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
                graphics.CopyFromScreen(new Point(rectangle.Left, rectangle.Top), Point.Empty, rectangle.Size);
            }
            bitmap.Save(Path.Combine(path, "UT" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + ".jpg"));
            bitmap.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

The entire project works fine on the native Windows version, all I have done so far is adjust the program to use the BlueStacks window which it does. I can set the BlueStacks emulator to use either OpenGL or DircetX as it's "Engine" it makes no difference at all. I have also tried to use the MeMu emulator but I get the same results.

When I check the pixel color at the x, y where I want to interact with the game it shows as black instead of the actual color green. I found many other questions that were getting black screens returned 
from similar operations, not sure if it's the same problem here.

I would appreciate any suggestions as I have searched a great deal and not found an answer yet.

Updated to show child window.

[Here is what Spy++ shows, the ""_ctl.Window" BlueStacksApp" is the window I'm after.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXWSP.jpg)

Comment: You're probably better off injecting your app into bluestack's and accessing the graphics library screen buffer memory rather than trying to find the window and screen shot it. Youll first need to detect what library is currently being used, i.e OpenGL / DX, and then find the relative canvas buffer. From there you can convert that byte array into an image.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take screenshot, I'd recommend not inventing the whole wheel again. You should probably take a look at [`ShareX`](https://github.com/sharex/sharex) project which has the same capabilities that you want.

[Here](https://github.com/ShareX/ShareX/tree/master/ShareX.ScreenCaptureLib) is the `ScreenCaptureLib` project (part of `ShareX`) which is dedicated to taking screenshot from screen.

Comment: Thanks Amir, I looked at that but it doesn't appear to deal with what i think is the actual issue. I believe that the problem is that the game that I am trying to capture screen info from is in a child window of Bluestacks. The FindWindow function that works fine with the native windows version of the game is not going deep enough to get to it.

Answer (score 0):

Use SecondBSWin handle instead of ForthBSWin handle

Comment: Please explain how that works and why it is supposed to solve the problem.